# Authorize.net will validating a credit card save it somewhere?

Tags: authorize.net

I was just wondering if I validate a credit card via authorize.net, will that CCN be saved somewhere so that I can manually process the CCN later?

My original approach was to validate the CCN and store that CCN somewhere in my own db but having a PCI compliant infrastructure is a heavy task and I would like to avoid that. Thus, I was hoping that maybe authorize.net will store that CCN somewhere for me and I can just charge that later?

Does anyone have any insight?

Thanks!

Comment: The term you're looking for is "tokenization", and they absolutely offer this. That said, I'd strongly recommend Stripe over Authorize for this sort of thing.

Comment: @ceejayoz this is exactly what i was looking for! thanks for your help